# SQL SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, select

I have a table with the following columns:

```
 id, teamA_id, teamB_id
```

Will it be possible to write a SELECT statement that gives both teamA_id and teamB_id in the same column?

EDIT:

Consider this example

From

```
 id, teamA_id, teamB_id
 1, 21, 45
 2, 34, 67
```

I need

```
Teams
21
45
34
67
```

Comment: you mean "one value" or "split into 2 rows"?

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways to do this, here is one method:

```
SELECT team_id
FROM
  (SELECT teamB_id AS team_id FROM my_table)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT teamA_id AS team_id FROM my_table)
```

(This solution also happens to satisfy the clarification in your edit.)

Comment: hahah, this would be the same column but two different rows. I up-voted because the (badly) worded question led me off to make a different assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT teamA_id || ' ' || teamB_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the SQL Concatenate function:

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html

> Each database provides a way to do this:
>
> ```
> * MySQL: CONCAT()
> * Oracle: CONCAT(), ||
> * SQL Server: +
> ```