# MySQL SELECT Statment to return 2 columns into 1

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a table with the following columns

```
 id, teamA_id, teamB_id
```

Will it be possible to do a MYSQL SELECT statement that gives both teamA_id and teamB_id in the same column?

EDIT

Consider this example

From

```
 id, teamA_id, teamB_id
 1, 21, 45
 2, 34, 67
```

I need

```
Teams
21
45
34
67
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768343/sql-select-statment

Comment: You asked the exact same question earlier today.  It's better to edit your original question if it needs clarification, instead of asking it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT teamA_id as 'Teams'
FROM Teams

UNION

SELECT teamB_id as 'Teams'
FROM Teams
```